# ReactiveCommand CanExecute is not updating button

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui, commandbinding

I´ve set up business logic handling a connection of a clientsoftware to a serversoftware.

That BL is encapsulated in this interface:

```
public interface IServerConnectionLogic
{
    IObservable<bool> Connected { get; }
    Task Connect();

    //...
}
```

In my viewmodel (based on ReactiveObject) I create my commands, that should trigger the server-connection:

```
CmdConnectToService = new ReactiveCommand(ServerConnectionLogic.Connected.Select(connected => !connected));
CmdConnectToService.Subscribe(_ => ServerConnectionLogic.Connect());
```

The command is bound to a button in my UI-XAML.

When pressing the button the subscribed lamda is hit and the "Connect" method is called.
Inside the Observable "Connected" is set to "true.

Also the lambda in the "CanExecute"-parameter of the constructor of the ReactiveCommand is hit.

But the UI is not updated. I would have expected the button to get disabled, sinde the observable "Connected" turns to "true" and the "Select" statement inverts my boolean value...

I´ve tried that with the "RibbonButton" from the WpfToolkit as well as with a "normal" Button. Both are not getting updated.

The same IObservable is also bound to a member field:

```
m_ServerConnected = new ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool>(ServerConnectionLogic.Connected, _ => raisePropertyChanged("ServerConnected"));
```

while "m_ServerConnected" is bound to a CheckBox (for testing) via a property. That one is working fine, so the observable must be working...

Does anyone have an idea what could be my issue?

Comment: How is `Connected` implemented? Perhaps this is because of subscription side-effects?

Comment: Currently "Connected" is just setting the IObservable<bool> to true:

        public virtual Task Connect()
        {
            m_Connected.OnNext(true);
            return Task.FromResult(true);

        }

I would not expect side effects here...